# Was Emmeline Vance's name inspired by the fantasy author, Jack Vance?

Tags: harry-potter, behind-the-scenes, inspiration, jk-rowling

When I read *Order of the Phoenix*, Emmeline Vance's name stood out to me immediately. I find It unlikely that Rowling ever read Vance, but seeing a witch named "Vance" in a fantasy work tends to stick out. Do we know if Emmeline Vance's name inspired by the fantasy author, Jack Vance?

Comment: JKR basically claims that nothing in her books is inspired by anyone living, presumably to avoid being sued.

Comment: I'd say [the Emmeline part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmeline_Pankhurst) is more likely to be a reference than the Vance part.

Comment: I can't find any relation to Jack Vance. But the name Emmeline means "work". Emmeline strikes me as a witch who works very hard - she was in the Order of the Phoenix twice. Maybe that's where the name comes from? But Vance is a pretty common name. Some 90,000+ people in the world have it in their name (first or last). Not counting the ones in the stories.

Comment: Or maybe the GTA character Lance Vance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No, the name Vance was most likely a coincidence.

As @Valorum says above in the comments, JKR claimed that nothing in her books is inspired by anyone living. (This does not extend to anyone dead. This means that some dead person might be the reason for the name "Vance" but I have yet to find them.) Also, the name "Vance" is a very common last name. Over 90,000 people have this last name in the entire world. In fact, the last name "Vance" is pretty common, ranked 8,335th by [Forebears](https://forebears.io/surnames/vance#:%7E:text=How%20Common%20Is%20The%20Last%20Name%20Vance%3F&text=The%20last%20name%20is%20the,found%20in%20Anglo%2DNorth%20America.).